# Options for adding a new field in the Quick Create layout

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to create  a  record in contact, if i want to add an **account** i click on **lookup** and create a **new** account. I want to add a new field named "Email" to be added when i am creating a record.

Comment: You mean a Quick Create feature, don't you? I believe you can't edit that "layout".

Comment: Ya in quick create only. Can we add new field in layout

Comment: No, you can't :(

Comment: I can confirm, the layout of the fields you see in the new account layout from contact lookup is not editable.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "custom lookup new button"? You've tagged the question as visualforce...

If you really have custom lookup functionality (or custom "create contact" page) similar to http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/visualforce-lookup.html or http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/ (images are broken, check the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20131108132746/http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/) version maybe) - you will have to check & modify that Visualforce page.

If you're using Quick Create - you can't modify it (and it's evil; seriously read Jeff's article). Use Chatter publisher actions instead...

If the VF page was done in a smart way the fields will be controlled with a "fieldset"  in which case you wouldn't need any coding to change it.